# Advantages and disadvantages of using many packages in a React Native App

Tags: react-native

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using many packages to build a mobile app using `react-native`?
Is it a good practice to keep the number of packages low? Does it affect performance? Does it affect the final product? Usability? Publishing? etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- having many packages doesn't necessarily affect performance, but it's enough for one faulty package to slow down performance.
- many packages equals harder maintenance, since you will probably want to keep all packages updated. try using "npm outdated" command to list packages that need an update
- depending on many external packages means if you need to change something, you will either need the authors to change it for you (might take a while) or dive into their code and try to change it yourself (might even take longer).
- my conclusion: write your own code whenever you're capable of doing so, and let others write code for you if the thing you are trying to achieve is too complicated for you, or will take too much of your time

Comment: So it's mostly maintenance, which is important/complex enough.